# WPF - Adding an overlay over increase and decrease button but under thumb in a slider

Tags: wpf, xaml, slider, controls, customization

Something like the default selection range, but since it supports only one range, I want to add a custom overlay to apply multiple selection ranges.
I tried creating a PART_SelectionRange, but it appears over the thumb. Is there any other way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

It's very hard to help users when they (*you*) provide so little information and no code. All the same, I believe that the `Panel.ZIndex Attached Property` *could* help you. It enables you to set the position of your controls in the z axis... from the front of the screen to the back. This would enable you to set your overlay under the `Thumb`, while setting the `Button`s under the overlay.

You can find out more about this property from the [Panel.ZIndex Attached Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.zindex.aspx) page at MSDN.

However, you *should* also be able to do this just by the order that the controls are declared in... later declared controls will appear 'on top of' earlier declared controls. So if you just declare your `Button`s first, then declare your overlay and then finally declare the `Thumb` control, you should get your desired result.